# Not found javax.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl in migration to JBoss7.2

Tags: web-services, migration, jax-ws, jboss7.x

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11
- Maven 3.6.3

Migration from:

- Jboss 5.2
- Java 7

I am migrating from JBoss 5.2 to Jboss 7.2 and I came across with an error with WS soap that does not find ProviderImpl because it is from the older implementation com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.
Should i remove the file resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider to get the default implementation on JBoss 7.2? or change it?

**EmpleoWeb**

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "EmpleoWeb", targetNamespace = "http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping", wsdlLocation = "http://intra.web.es/WebServicesEntireX/services/EmpleoWeb?wsdl")
public class EmpleoWeb extends Service {

    private final static URL EMPLEOWEB_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException EMPLEOWEB_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName EMPLEOWEB_QNAME = new QName("http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping", "EmpleoWeb");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://intra.web.es/WebServicesEntireX/services/EmpleoWeb?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        EMPLEOWEB_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        EMPLEOWEB_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public EmpleoWeb() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), EMPLEOWEB_QNAME);
    }

    public EmpleoWeb(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), EMPLEOWEB_QNAME, features);
    }

    public EmpleoWeb(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, EMPLEOWEB_QNAME);//ERROR
    }
    ...
```

**resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider**

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

**Error log**

**Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found**

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:83)
    ... 146 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error while searching for service [javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider]
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:65)
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:62)
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.firstByServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:74)
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96)
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-ejb.jar//es.caib.accfor.business.io.ws.silcoi.entity.wsdl.empleo.EmpleoWeb.<init>(EmpleoWeb.java:50)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-ejb.jar//es.caib.accfor.business.io.ws.silcoi.boundary.SilcoiClient.setWsdlEmpleoWeb(SilcoiClient.java:339)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-ejb.jar//es.caib.accfor.business.io.ws.silcoi.boundary.SilcoiClient.<init>(SilcoiClient.java:45)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-back.war//es.caib.accfor.presentation.back.io.ws.silcoi.SilcoiBean.init(SilcoiBean.java:43)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1211)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at javax.xml.ws.api@1.0.0.Final-redhat-1//javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.firstByServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:67)
    ... 158 more
```

Comment: The problem looks like the com.sun.xml.*internal*.ws.spi.ProviderImpl package does not exists anymore in Java 11, but I tried to add library dependencies jaxws-rt and javax.jws-api and modifing META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider text inside by com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl but nothing seems to work

Comment: The problem must be related with JDK 11 migration from Java 7 and removed java.xml.ws modules of Java EE.
Migration guide from oracle https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html
JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Oracle JDK Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html) and [JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)

I added the following depending to maven project to keep up running.

```
    <!-- JAXWS for Java 11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I had to download jaxws-rt-2.3.0.jar and added to /lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the removal of the default implementation from java 11: [Not found javax.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl in migration to JBoss7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206054/not-found-javax-xml-ws-spi-providerimpl-in-migration-to-jboss7-2-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).